# How can I programmatically map XML fields in Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm trying to programmatically map some fields from an XML file to a table in excel.

Manually, I go to the developer tab, hit the source button, select XML Maps, press the add button, paste in the path to my XML file, and Excel creates the XML map. I then click and drag the fields to certain cells in my worksheet. This works fine.

I figured I could use the macro recorder to capture this, however the actual mapping of the fields to the cells does not get recorded. The only thing that gets recorded is the creation of the map:

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add( _
        "path_to_my_XML_file" _
        , "feed").Name = "feed_Map"
```

how can I programmatically map the fields to a range? Is it possible in VBA?

Comment: The [XPath object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff840102.aspx) might be what you need